# VT-x and VT-d Enabled in BIOS, but not working

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bios, virtualization, vmware

My System:
Win10 Pro 20H2
i7-4790k
GTX-1060 6G
msi z97

In the BIOS, VT-x and VT-d are both enabled, but if I try to launch a VM in VMWare or VBox, I get an Error that VT-x is disabled. The Intel Processor Identification Utility also shows VT-x as disabled.

I have had Hyper-V and Sandbox enabled once, but I disabled it.
Core Isolation in Windows Defender is also disabled.
Windows Hypervisor Platform is also disabled.

[Windows Feature On/Off Screenshot (German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79vGB.png)

[Core-Isolation / Memory Integrity Screenshot (German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rotD.png)

[VMWare Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HM07.png)

Comment: You might also need to disable the "Plattform fur virtuelle computer" as it is essentially a VM hosting platform for Windows. It is needed by WSL2 I believe and may be using the extensions as well.

Comment: @Mokubai - The current version of both VMWare Workstation and VirtualBox support it though since the author is running 20H2.  Something else probably an incompatible Hypervisor or security software  is causing the author’s problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Mokubai that was it :)

Comment: @Ramhound I have Avira Prime as Antivirus, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling "Plattform für virtuelle Computer" solved the Problem, Thanks to @Mokubai

Comment: I hope you understand by disabling that you have prevented yourself from using WSL2.